# Embedding Google-Maps iFrame by User-Defined Coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, iframe

I am currently working on a website and got stuck at a little problem. I want the user to be able to choose COORDINATES on a Google Map. So I embeded a Maps-Iframe on my Site and when the user clicks a button, the center coordinates of the map (as well as the zoom, tilt and map-type) will be saved in some variables. No problem until here.

Now I want to be able to create the HTML for an iFrame to display the Map. I should maybe explain, that it is used for an online richtext editor (selfmade) - which should be able to save a chosen view on a google maps iframe.

I have got the center coordinates, the tilt level, the zoom level, the map type - everything saved in variables after the user clicked on a button when he decided that he would like to save the current google maps position. How can I get the HTML for the iFrame? I want something like this JavaScript-Code that doesn't work... You know, just some HTML that can be saved like any other text:

```
<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://www.google.at/maps/@" + CenterCoordinates['G'] + "," + CenterCoordinates['K'] + "," + Zoom + "z,output=embed'></iframe>
```

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

When the user clicks the button underneath the Google-Maps-iFrame, the current View should get saved and an iFrame with exactly the same coordinates, zoom, tilt, maptype should be created and inserted into a contenteditable iframe. The function called after clicking the button only does this:

```
RichTextField.document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://www.google.at/maps/@" + CenterCoordinates['G'] + "," + CenterCoordinates['K'] + "," + Zoom + "z,output=embed'></iframe>");
```

Comment: Is CenterCoordinates javascript object, then provide a js code.

Comment: @ebilgin
CenterCoordinates = Map.getCenter();
Zoom = Map.getZoom();
Tilt = Map.getTilt();
MapType = Map.getMapTypeId();

Sorry - The variable names should be lowercase.

Comment: `CenterCoordinates['G']` and `CenterCoordinates['K']` are undocumented properties of the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  They can and will change with every release of the API, **do not use them, use the documented functions (`.lat()` and `.lng()`) instead**.